# How to reset a function on "click" using Bootstrap 4 carousel

Tags: javascript, forms, bootstrap-4

I'm building a form in Bootstrap 4 that is broken out into multiple parts using a carousel.

What I would like to do is when the user completes the inputs for each section, the "next" button removes the `disabled` attribute.
I was able to figure this out for the first slide, but I can't figure out how to reset the function when it goes to the next active slide.

I'm trying to use vanilla Javascript. I'd also like to get the validation classes to work for each section using the next button, as opposed to submit.

Any help would be much appreciated. I'm still working to get a lot better at Javascript!

Here is my Fiddle: [Guided Carousel](https://jsfiddle.net/uxcqL9je/1/)

HTML

```
<div class="container m-5">
<h1 class="text-center">Guided Form</h1>
<div id="slider1" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel" data-interval="false">
    <ol class="carousel-indicators row">
        <li class="col-md-4 active" data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="0">1</li>
        <li class="col-md-4" data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="1">2</li>
        <li class="col-md-4" data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="2">3</li>
    </ol>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6 offset-md-3 mt-5">
            <div class="carousel-inner" style="height:300px;">
                <p id="alert"></p>
                <form method="POST" action="" id="guideForm" novalidate="">
                    <div class="carousel-item active">  
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="InputFirstName">First Name</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control first-name" id="InputFirstName" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="First Name" required>
                            <div class="valid-feedback">Success! You've done it.</div>
                            <div class="invalid-feedback">No, you missed this one.</div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="carousel-item">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="InputLastName">Last Name</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="InputLastName" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="Last Name" required>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="carousel-item">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="InputEmail">Last Name</label>
                            <input type="email" class="form-control" id="InputEmail" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="Email" required>
                        </div>
                       <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" id="submitBtn">Submit</button>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <a class="carousel-control-prev d-none" href="#slider1" role="button" data-slide="prev">
      <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
    </a>
    <button id="nextBtn" class="carousel-control-next d-none" href="#slider1" role="button" data-slide="next" type="submit" disabled>
      <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
    </button>
  </div>
```

JS

```
var form = document.querySelector('form .active')
var fn = document.querySelectorAll('.active #InputFirstName')
var required_inputs = document.querySelector('.active #InputFirstName')
var ln = document.querySelectorAll('.active #InputLasttName')
var required_inputs = document.querySelector('.active #InputLastName')
var register = document.querySelector('#nextBtn')
form.addEventListener('keyup', function(e) {
    var disabled = false
    fn.forEach(function(input, index) {
        if (input.value === '' || !input.value.replace(/\s/g, '').length) {
            disabled = true
        }
    })
    if (disabled) {
        register.setAttribute('disabled', 'disabled')
    } else {
        register.removeAttribute('disabled')

    }
})
```